# Eucalyptus 4.4.4 Eucaconsole Crash After Login

Tags: eucalyptus

With the help of folks here and at github I have a clean startup log and  working login page for my Eucaconsole.  I've configured an account and user for the console via

```
euare-accountcreate -a myconsoleaccount

euare-useraddloginprofile --as-account myconsoleaccount -u admin -p cleverpassword
```

-On the user-side I can reliably generate a failed login message using a known bad password.  I do this so I can see the difference between good/bad password behavior.

-When I authenticate, seemingly successfuly, my browser moves to a 504 Gateway Timeout error and I find the following error info in my /var/log/eucaconsole.log:

```
2018-11-05 15:37:53 INFO Authenticated Eucalyptus user: myconsoleaccount/admin from 10.0.0.7
2018-11-05 15:40:54 ERROR Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 45, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 93, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 242, in __call__
    response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 217, in invoke_subrequest
    response = handle_request(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eucaconsole/tweens.py", line 126, in __call__
    response = self.handler(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eucaconsole/tweens.py", line 88, in tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eucaconsole/tweens.py", line 62, in tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eucaconsole/tweens.py", line 51, in tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 163, in handle_request
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 596, in __call__
    return view(context, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 329, in attr_view
    return view(context, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 305, in predicate_wrapper
    return view(context, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 355, in rendered_view
    result = view(context, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 477, in _class_requestonly_view
    response = getattr(inst, attr)()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eucaconsole/views/login.py", line 214, in handle_login
    return self.handle_euca_login()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eucaconsole/views/login.py", line 306, in handle_euca_login
    session['supported_platforms'] = self.get_account_attributes(['supported-platforms'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eucaconsole/views/__init__.py", line 318, in get_account_attributes
    attributes = conn.describe_account_attributes(attribute_names=attribute_names)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 4447, in describe_account_attributes
    [('item', AccountAttribute)], verb='POST')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1170, in get_list
    response = self.make_request(action, params, path, verb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1116, in make_request
    return self._mexe(http_request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe
    raise ex
BadStatusLine: ''
```

Is there another log with more details?  I'm not seeing any explicit version conflicts as were present in my previous issues. Any other ideas?

[Solved.  Above is red-herring info that was generated because of basic connectivity issues.]

Steve Jones comment on his answer below is correct. I find the documentation a bit lacking here because I did have the `ufshost` value pointing to the UFS host...by IP, by DNS Name and even right there by pointing at localhost. In all of these cases I could use my traditional admin toolset to confirm connectivity from the eucaconsole to the target ufs host via tcpdumps generated when making a login attempt with the eucaconsole.  But there's a big difference between providing the `ufshost` value with a good target host and making sure it matches the `system.dns.dnsdomain` value specified when following the Runtime Environment config instructions.  The documentation for the eucaconsole handles information about this setting with no nuance and effectively just tells us the IP or hostname is fine when in fact most users will find themselves in a config scenario where they have configured Euca DNS and require a much more specific value.  Thank you for clarifying Steve!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed the rest of the configuration steps?:

http://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.4/index.html#shared/console_config_server_address.html

From the error it looks like the console cannot connect to your eucalyptus cloud, so I would first check this setting:

`ufshost=127.0.0.1`

in the console configuration ("/etc/eucaconsole/console.ini") and perhaps verify that you are able to use `euca2ools` from wherever you have installed the console.

You should also use `euserv-describe-services` to verify that all services are running on your eucalyptus cloud.

If still having issues it would be useful to describe what settings you have configured and what you are trying to set up (e.g. ssl/nginx)

Comment: I'm running the console on the same host as UFS and CLC so I took from the install guide that I should leave the console.ini setting of ufshost=127.0.0.1 . All of my services are green except the imaging backend which I have yet to configure.  I'll see if I can get any useful info by attempting euca2ools connections.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Also my goal is to get a simple PoC w/ VPCMIDO installation off the ground.  I've followed the installation guide to this point and intend to run CLC, UFS and Eucaconsole on the same host.  I've got separate hosts for 1 Walrus,  1CC,  1 SC and 1 NODE.  So far all services are registered and green and I was at the point in the install where I am trying to configure the console.

Comment: Yes.  I can use euca2ools from the console host
euare-accountlist
(eucalyptus)database 0001...

Comment: The command that you would want to check is `euca-describe-account-attributes`. The `ufshost` should typically be set to whatever you configured for `system.dns.dnsdomain`.

Comment: The above comment is the correct answer and finally got the eucaconsole working. See my edit in the original question for expanded detail.